# How to remove duplicated keys in reverse order from dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling to remove same keys from a dictionary in the case below:

```
{('cat', 'tiger'): 18,
 ('tiger', 'cat'): 18,
 ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7,
 ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}
```

In this case, I consider reverse order `('cat', 'tiger'): 18` and `('tiger', 'cat'): 18` as same keys and try to make a new dictionary like below

```
 {('cat', 'tiger'): 18,
  ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}
```

What I am trying is adapt any reverse order case, when I have a similar dictionary like `{(('cage', 'cat'), 5),(('cat', 'cage'), 5)}` to be merged or removed, either one.

Comment: These are not dictionaries....

Comment: I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind arbitrarily dropping one of the duplicates. Which one is dropped and why? It seems to be different for each case.

Comment: I am sorry, I had a little bit mistake and now I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something along the following lines:

```
d = {('cat', 'tiger'): 18,
     ('tiger', 'cat'): 18,
     ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7,
     ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}

result = {tuple(sorted(x)): y for x, y in d.items()}
# {('cat', 'tiger'): 18, ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7}
```

In this `dict` comprehension, the last encountered value for each set of "equal" keys wins. With your sample data, this shouldn't matter because those keys have equla values. Note that this also just sorts the tuples, regardless of the sorted version actually occuring in the original `dict`.

Comment: Never realized you could use tuples for keys. I suppose it makes sense. :P I'm guessing lists don't work, though?

Comment: No, lists don't. It has to be a hashable type.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to do. And I apologize my incomprehensible question...But in this way, tuple is functioning to remove duplicated ?

Comment: @user7421972 Sorting makes makes all permutations equal, but `sorted` returns a `list` which is mutable and not hashable and, thus, cannot be used as dictionary key. Since dictionary keys are unique, the `dict` comprehension discards any repeated keys (i.e. keeps the last). Hope that helped.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `tuple` values as keys, but `tuple` objects are ordered, so `('a','b')` is different than `('b','a')`. A simple solution? Use an unordered yet hashable container, i.e. a frozenset would work:

```
>>> data = {('cat', 'tiger'): 18,
...  ('tiger', 'cat'): 18,
...  ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7,
...  ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}
>>>
>>> data
{('cat', 'tiger'): 18, ('tiger', 'cat'): 18, ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7, ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}
>>> {frozenset(k):v for k,v in data.items()}
{frozenset({'cat', 'tiger'}): 18, frozenset({'gentleman', 'chines'}): 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the order of the two items in the key... and the value associated with them is always the same, the easiest would probably be, assuming your starting dictionary named `old_dict`:

```
new_dict = dict()
for (key, value) in old_dict.items():
    new_dict[tuple(sorted(key))] = value
```

You just iterate through key/value pairs and add them into `new_dict`. Since we now sorted the key and then turned the resulting list back into tuple, we make sure than any reappearing couple just overwrites the previous entry.

Answer (score 0):

instead of deleting items from that , you can take what you want and leave rest.

```
data={('cat', 'tiger'): 18,
 ('tiger', 'cat'): 18,
 ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7,
 ('gentleman', 'chines'): 7}


track={}
for i,j in data.items():
    track[tuple(sorted(i))]=j

print(track)
```

output:

```
{('cat', 'tiger'): 18, ('chines', 'gentleman'): 7}
```